# How to avoid AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' webscraping subreddits?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Trying to make a program that gets a random subreddit, displays the title to the terminal, asks the user if they want to see it and if so opens a browser with that subreddit.

I'm running into an issue here whilst doing so. I am very new with python/beautiful soup just started using it a few weeks ago for school any help will be very appreciated.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

while True:
    url = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    title = soup.find(class_="_2yYPPW47QxD4lFQTKpfpLQ").text ## this is supposed to get the title of the subreddit and this is where my error is occurring

    print(f"{title} \nSelect this subreddit? (Y/N)")
    ans = input("").lower()

    if ans == "y":
        url = "https://www.reddit.com/%s" % title ## Some issue, not sure what
        webbrowser.open(url)
        break
    elif ans == "n":
        print("Try again!")
        continue
    else:
        print("Wrong choice!")
        break
```

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find(class_="_2yYPPW47QxD4lFQTKpfpLQ")` returns None if there is no element with the given class, That's why you got this error

Try to catch the error using `try-except` and print something if soup not found any title.

Try this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import webbrowser

while True:
    url = requests.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/random")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, "html.parser")
    try:
        title = soup.find(class_="_2yYPPW47QxD4lFQTKpfpLQ").text
    ## this is supposed to get the title of the subreddit and this is where my error is occurring
    except AttributeError:
        print("Title Not Found")

    else:
        print(f"{title} \nSelect this subreddit? (Y/N)")
        ans = input("").lower()

        if ans == "y":
            url = "https://www.reddit.com/%s" % title ## Some issue, not sure what
            webbrowser.open(url)
            break
        elif ans == "n":
            print("Try again!")
            continue
        else:
            print("Wrong choice!")
            break
```

Comment: This did work! But unfortunately that would render my program useless. Is there an alternative so I can ensure I am getting the title of the subreddit somehow?

Comment: I will edit the answer if I got some solution

Answer (score 2):

Element you try to `find()` is not available in your `soup` and calling a methode on `None` raises this error, so:

1. Always and at first check your response, does it include the expected information - You will be detected as bot, so add some headers:

   ```
   url = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/random', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
   ```
2. Avoid to select your elements by dynamic looking classes, instead us static identifier and HTML structure, also select the right elements:

   ```
   soup.h2.get_text(strip=True)
   ```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, webbrowser

while True:
    url = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/random', headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content)
    title = soup.h2.get_text(strip=True)
    print(f"{title} \nSelect this subreddit? (Y/N)")
    ans = input("").lower()

    if ans == "y":
        url = f"https://www.reddit.com/{title}"
        webbrowser.open(url)
        break
    elif ans == "n":
        print("Try again!")
        continue
    else:
        print("Wrong choice!")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for this information it is extremely helpful. Though I believe the issue of not getting a title still persists. the terminal says "title not defined" Any work around to get a title no matter what of the random sub reddit?

Comment: There is no such message in my example - What is your response or soup telling you  if you print it? Is the element available?

Comment: I just realized my error, you changed code in the if statement too. it works perfectly now thank you SO much!!